# DOMException on generating pdf using jsPDF in angular 2+

Tags: angular, jspdf

I have a simple typescript function that allows me to export the picture and a text on it. The picture is on the web and has a valid url. But I received the following error:

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://docs.gimp.org/es/images/tutorials/quickie-jpeg-100.jpg'.

The code that I use is below:

```
getPdf () {
    const imgData = 'https://docs.gimp.org/es/images/tutorials/quickie-jpeg-100.jpg';

    const pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', 15, 40, 100, 100);
    pdf.text(30, 30, 'test');
    pdf.save('my_pdf.pdf');
 }
```

I looked at their documentation and their live demo. It seems that I have the same codes. You may also find a plunker [Here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/ZplwWZFyKaj7j41I?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using image url as an Data url. As per JSPDF Demo

> "You'll need to make your image into a Data URL"
>
> "Use http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker"

You can check that out here on [jsPDF site](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

So basically, download your image in your local system, generate data url from it, replace it with your url and it'll work as expected. No need to change anything else.
You can find plunker for the same [here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/0SS400bdwGDmlBFw?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1)

```
const imgData = 'imageDataUrl Here';
```

Comment: i am trying to follow your method for converting a simple html table. can you please see the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/nlzVpS6eVrlSfTYY and correct me ( i guess i messed up where u said // It's because you are using image url as an Data url// ).